# Предупреждение, если в тексте вопроса или ответа вставлен неотформатированный код

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, нытьё, редактор

Только что заметил на en.SO такую особенность: если в ответ просто вставить код, не отформатировав его как код, то выскочит предупреждение, что очень круто, я считаю. На ru.SO такого поведения не наблюдается.

Вопрос: когда у нас такое будет?

> [image: Скриншот]

Comment: А еще на картинке видно баг с "community wiki/draft saved"

Answer (score 3):

Упоминание этой функции есть на MSE аж в ноябре 2011: [Incomprehensible "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113810/339911)

Вы уверены, что данный функционал по-прежнему не доступен на ruSO? Попробуйте ввести тот же код, на который возникла ошибка на enSO. Допускаю, что тут могут быть важны ещё и метки, установленные на вопросе.

Перевод текста был произведён на ruSO первый раз 2 года назад. На текущий момент он выглядит так:

> Кажется, ваше сообщение содержит код, не оформленный соответствующим образом. Пожалуйста, выделите весь код 4 отступами с помощью кнопки на панели инструментов или воспользуйтесь комбинацией клавиш CTRL+K. Чтобы получить дополнительную справку по редактированию, нажмите значок [?] в панели инструментов.

Лично я, правда, ни разу не видел подобных сообщений. Но я всегда форматировал код как код.

Comment: В том то и дело, что на ru.SO сколько сижу, никогда такого не выскакивало. А вот сегодня решил вдруг ответ на en.SO написать, вставил код, чуть растягиваю окошко редактора - сразу выскакивает это предупреждение. Сейчас еще раз проверил - на en.SO работает, на ru.SO никакого предупреждения не выскакивает.

Comment: @insolor возможно дело в какой-то локальной настройке сайте. Надо пингануть Николаса.

Comment: Данная функция не была активирована ранее. Я активировал её для всех участников с репутацией ниже 200 баллов. 200 баллов является значением по умолчанию для всех сайтов Сети, его можно изменить, при необходимости. Если необходимость появилась, напишите об этом Николаю.

Comment: @AdamLear Большое спасибо!

Comment: @alexolut, _"выделите весь код 4 отступами"_ - надо бы по-человечески сформулировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy заменить на "пробелами"?

Comment: @alexolut, всё равно непонятно получится же? 4 пробелами в начале каждой строки? Но хотелось бы как-то покороче.